# Find the closest value from given value from file bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

can someone help me with script/oneliner in bash, that finds the closest given value from file..? example:

i have these values in file:

```
SJ ENG MGR DE CJ RU CHI JPN 
1   2   3  10 20 50 100 900
```

i need to find the closest value to for example "90". The result should be 100 + the column in which is the value like : 100 CHI or something like that .

I remaked my input from line to column and applied this code

```
awk -v c=1 -v t=35 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$c}END{print v}'
```

it worked, but i cant remake this line of code into code that works in line. Its working with columns but not with lines and i need working solution like in my example.

Thank you.

//edit

ok, so im still stuck here, im trying it with this input

```
SJ     ENG    MGR    DE   CJ   RU    CHI     JPN 
9,50   3,10   3,12  3,70 3,50  3,80   3,75 3,90
```

and im looking for closest number to "5,50" and its still finds 3,10 as the closest, which is not true, it should be 3,90. Im using correct locale now.

Comment: What have you already tried? What happened?

Comment: I remaked my input from line to column and applied this code 'awk -v c=1 -v t=35 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$c}END{print v}'', it worked, but i cant remake this line of code into code that works in line. Its working with columns but not with lines and i need working solution like in my example.

Comment: Put that in your question with proper formatting please :)

Comment: Just two lines in the file? Walk the fields in the first one and build up a field number->value mapping then walk the fields in the second one and do your closest matching and save the corresponding field number. Then print both.

Comment: What do you mean by `Its working with columns but not with lines`? Your posted example is ENTIRELY about columns in a single line. If you have multiple lines, edit your question to show that input plus the associated expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over each field to find the minimum difference between the value and the target value.  Surprisingly, awk does not implement `abs()`, so I've provided one here.

```
awk -v target=90 '
  # store the header for each column
  NR == 1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) header[i] = $i; next}

  function abs(val) { return (val < 0 ? -1*val : val) }

  {
    min = abs($1 - target)
    min_idx = 1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      diff = abs($i - target)
      if (diff < min) {
        min = diff
        min_idx = i
      }
    }
    print $min_idx, header[min_idx]
  }
' file
```

```
100 CHI
```

---

To summarize Ed's instructions to make the script locale-aware:

```
env LC_ALL=en_DK.utf8 gawk --use-lc-numeric -v target=5,5 '
  # ... script unchanged
' file2
```

```
3,90 JPN
```

Comment: For min or max calculations you should always init the variable with the first data value rather than picking some arbitrary one. If you make that change I'll delete my answer as then they'll be identical and you got there a couple of mins ahead of me.

Comment: im sorry to un-answer this question, but i encountered an issue with this and its my fault, i need this done with real numbers, like find closest between 3,20 and 3,95 for number 3,7. It is possible with a small change within this code? thanks again

Comment: The answer is correct as written. You just need to set your locale to whatever locale you are in where the decimal point is a `,`. Google "locale comma" and see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conversion.html. Looks like `LC_ALL=en_DK.utf-8` would work for that.

Comment: dont know how notifications works on this site, so i posted problem into another answer, so if you guys have time to help me further...i was looking for my locale/encoding, what decimal point uses my encode, and its "," so its okay, but still it doesnt work for example i posted in the answer

Comment: You'll notice a small link "edit" below your question. That's where this new information should go. Then you can delete that "answer"

Comment: You now just need to add the `-N` (or `--use-lc-numeric`) argument to gawk (and use gawk!): `awk -N -v target=90 '...` Again - read the reference I pointed you to earlier, https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conversion.html.